# How to fix JSONDecode error with yfinance?

Tags: python, json, yfinance

Yfinance was working perfectly till last evening. Thereafter, I installed Docker on my system, and everything was working fine before I went to sleep last night.

This morning after, I woke up, I found yfinance was giving JSON Decode errors in my cron jobs. I presumed it was because of Docker, so I uninstalled it and tried. It does not work still.

Things I have already tried this morning:

1. Uninstalling and installing with -U no-cache-dir as specified by RanaRanoussi
2. Modified the base.py method by adding the {'user-agent':'Firefox'}
3. Used the time.sleep(1) after every ticker data download
4. also, uninstalled and installed the pandas-data-webreader

After every step mentioned above - 1,2,3 -, the code runs but only once. Then it starts to fail.

Comment: Please explain _what_ your error is, in the questino.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted all files of yFinance in the Python folder, and then uninstalled yfinance. I also deleted docker and all its files from my system. Thereafter, I re-installed finance 0.1.64, and now it's working fine.